# Number of inflection points of $(x-2)^6(x-3)^9$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Find the number of inflection points of $(x-2)^6(x-3)^9$

**Attempt:**

If $f(x)$ has $n$ critical points then even $f(x+a)$ will also have $n$ critical points.

So we can simplify it to finding the number of inflection points  of $(x)^6(x-1)^9$.

I have evaluated the double derivative to be:

$$6(x-1)^7x^4(35x^2-28x +5)$$

Clearly, the double derivative is $0$ at $4$ points, $0$, $1$ and the roots of the quadratic. But curvature is not changing around $x=0$ so it's not an inflection point.

Thus, there should be $3$ inflection points.

But answer given is $1$ inflection point only.

Please let me know what concept am I missing on.

I tried my level best to zoom into the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pese2qhwml) and catch three critical points but there appears to be only one.

Comment: Try to plug in your possible inflection point values into the third derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

$$f'(x)=3(x-3)^8(x-2)^5(5x-12)=0 \implies x=3,2,\frac{12}5$$

and

$$f''(x)=6(x-3)^7(x-2)^4(35x^2-168x+201)=0 \\\implies x_1=2,\,x_2=3,\,x_{3,4}=\frac{12}5\pm\frac{\sqrt{3/7}}{5}$$

and since $p(x)=35x^2-168x+201\implies p(12/5)\neq 0$ the unique stationary inflection point is at $x=3$ otherwise, if we look at general inflection points, by the sign of $f''(x)$ the inflection points are three at

$$x_2=3,\,x_{3,4}=\frac{12}5\pm\frac{\sqrt{3/7}}{5}$$

Comment: From where do you know that $x=3$ is an inflection point?

Comment: https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

Comment: Oh have you differentiated the original function instead? Thats a tedious way right? Please see my method and let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: also the third derivative $$f'''(x)=6\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{3} \left( x-3 \right) ^{6} \left( 455\,{x}^{3
}-3276\,{x}^{2}+7839\,x-6234 \right) 
$$ is Zero for $x=3$!!!

Comment: you must compute higher derivatives, $f^{(v)},f^{(vII)},...$ and so on.

Comment: Forget the derivative calculator! and use your brain.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm looking for the inflection stationary point and we have $f'(3)=0$ and $f''(x)$ change sign at $x=3$.

Comment: What is a inflection stationary point?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Categorization_of_points_of_inflection

Comment: see also herehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test

Comment: And this is the truth?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Since the OP noticed that the answer given assume only one inflection point, it is possible that the problem is asking for stationary inflection point that is with horizontal tangent.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Otherwise we have more inflection points.

Comment: Ok i understand, you mean "horizontaler Wendepunkt" in german, sorry i don't know the english word.

Comment: I agree, not all inflection points are stationary points.

Comment: This is true, inflection points must be not stationary!

Comment: I have found horizontal turning Point as the english word

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes exactly as for $y=x^3$.

Comment: Yes it is, like $x=0$ for $y=x^3$, and here is the fith derivative:

Comment: $$f^{(v)}(x)=360\, \left( x-2 \right)  \left( x-3 \right) ^{4} \left( 1001\,{x}^{5}
-12012\,{x}^{4}+57486\,{x}^{3}-137148\,{x}^{2}+163119\,x-77376
 \right) 
$$

Comment: I think it must go on..let me see!

Comment: $$f^{(VII})=45360\, \left( x-3 \right) ^{2} \left( 715\,{x}^{6}-10582\,{x}^{5}+
65065\,{x}^{4}-212740\,{x}^{3}+390115\,{x}^{2}-380410\,x+154105
 \right) 
$$

Comment: Or we can investigate the change of sign of $f''(x)$ which is not that hard in this case.

Comment: Hm and $$f^{(IX)}(3)=598752000$$

Comment: But you must how the Change of sign.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes indeed$ f''(x)=0$ at $4$ points and by the study of the sign it is easy to see that three are inflection points.

Comment: @gimusi **Please** explain what is the difference between stationary and non stationary points of inflection.

Comment: @Abcd Stationary inflection points are also critical points that is $f'(x)=0$and then the tangent is horizontal. Since you were referring to an answer with 1 inflection point I thought that maybe your problem was referring to this special kind of inflection point. Otherwise you are right there are exactly 3 inflection points. refer also to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Categorization_of_points_of_inflection.

Comment: @gimusi thanks. Could you give me some examples of non stationary points of inflection? I would be grateful. It seems that in our sylllabus we only have stationary points of inflection and that's why the answer given is 1.

Comment: It is only one inflection point,$$x=3,f(3)$$ no others., it is horizental turning Point.

Comment: @Abcd Consider for example $f(x)=x^3+\sin x$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What about $x=\frac{12}5\pm\frac{\sqrt{3/7}}{5}$?

Comment: What is this?,From where does it come?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Did you read my question and attempt?

Comment: I haven't checked the other Solutions of $f''(x)=0$, WA says also there are three inflection Point.

Comment: I did read your question completely.

Comment: Your second derivative is wrong, so i have found no other points

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner So did you see that I have (x-1)^7x^4(35x^2 - 28 x+5) and thus there should be 3 points of inflection?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have found the second derivatives for $f(x+2)$ not $f(x)$ because if f(x) has n inflection points then even f(x+2) will have n inflection points.

Comment: One Moment, i will check this...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+(x)%5E6(x-1)%5E9+twice

Comment: Yes ok it is $$f''(x)=6\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{4} \left( x-3 \right) ^{7} \left( 35\,{x}^{2}
-168\,x+201 \right) 
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am talking about something completely different.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It appears you didn't read my attempt.

Comment: Ok the reason is  it is to hot for me!

Comment: And look how much is written about your problem.

Comment: And can you please write down, what is open now? Or is all solved?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81088/discussion-on-answer-by-gimusi-number-of-inflection-points-of-x-26x-39).

Answer (score 2):

It may help to see a very vertically magnified plot of the second derivative (of the original untranslated function).

[image]

Given that the inflection points can only be at $x = 2$, $x = 3$, or the roots of the quadratic term $35x^2-168x+201$ (i.e., $r_{1, 2} = \frac{12}{5} \pm \frac{\sqrt{21}}{35}$), the plot above shows that there must be three inflection points: at $x = r_1 \approx 2.269$, $x = r_2 \approx 2.531$, and $x = 3$.

Comment: But he was searching for horizontal turning points, and there is only one!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I looked in the OP statement, and I don't see that.  The quoted problem says "inflection points."  Where was the clarification to "horizontal turning point"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the graph! Very helpful.

Comment: However, the curve is so smooth that it is really hard to clearly spot the inflection points even in this graph.

Comment: @Abcd: Keep in mind that the inflection points are those at which the above graph (the second derivative) changes sign.  So the inflection points at $x = r_1$ and $x = r_2$ should be pretty easy to see.  The one at $x = 3$ is tough, admittedly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious from the degree of the factors:

$f(2) = 0, f(3) = 0\\
f'(2) = 0, f'(3)= 0\\
f''(2) = 0, f''(3)= 0$

Since $f(x) \le 0$ when $x< 3$ and $f(x) > 0$ when $x>3,$ $f(2)$ is a maximum (and not an inflection point, and $f(3)$ is an inflection point and not a min or a max.

There must be a point $c\in (2,3)$ where $f'(c) = 0$ and it must be a local minimum.

There is a point of inflection in $(2,c)$ and one in $(c,3)$

That is 3 points of inflection.